# border-bottom not appearing for all TDs,only appearing for the TDs of last TR

Tags: css

I have got a table here that Im trying to apply some CSS rules to it.I have got a CSS rule in place to set the border bottom and border top to be in red and green respectively. For some reason border-bottom is not appearing for all TDs but only for the TDs of last TR. Any reason why.

```
    table{
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    table td{
        border-top:solid 4px green;
        border-bottom:solid 2px red;
    }
<table width="500px">
        <tr>
            <td>Computers</td>
            <td>£900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laptops</td>
            <td>£600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Keyboards</td>
            <td>£20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hard Drives</td>
            <td>£80</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Because the borders are overlapping, the green border is "on top of" the red border

Comment: Can I get it not to overlap?

Comment: `border-collapse: separate;` on the table instead of `collapse;`

Comment: @Andy dude thanks,how do I mark ur reply as the answer?

Comment: I'll make it as an actual answer, then you click the green tick next to it

Answer (score 0):

The borders are over lapping, the green is on top of the red. To rectify this set `border-collapse: separate;` instead of `border-collapse: collapse;`